# Have to call service twice to receive values

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Im trying to get a list from github api but I'm only receiving values when I call the service for the second time.

I have this function on the component

```
repos;
    showRepos(userLogin) {
      this.buscaService.getRepos(userLogin).subscribe(
        repo => this.repos = repo
      )
      console.log('this repos', this.repos);
    }
```

and on the service I have a simple `http.get`:

```
  getRepos(user) {
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + user + '/repos');
  }
```

The first time I call the service it show that this.repos is undefined, but when I call it for the second time it shows me the array. How can I make it print on the first time?

Comment: Try: `repo => { this.repos = repo; console.log('this repos', this.repos); }`. In your code, `console.log` is called before the async subscribe callback.

Comment: oh, its realy that, thank you Connors